# Duplicate const qualifier allowed in C but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic, constants

Sample code snippet

```
const const const int x = 10;   
int main()
{}
```

gets compiled in C but not in C++. Why does it get compiled in C? I thought this would fail in C as well. Never mind.

Which part of the C++ Standard forbids the use of duplicate `const` and which part of the C standard allows this?

Comment: Is that `duplicate`? or repeated? :P

Comment: x is `const` and I *really* mean it this time!!

Comment: It makes no sense, only confusion. The latter fits more in the C++ language, however.

Comment: May I ask how you stumbled upon this? Did you accidentally write `const` multiple times?

Comment: @FredOverflow : Yes! Actually I was writing some C code and by mistake used `const` two times and was surprised to see the code getting compiled. :)

Comment: C allows it and C++ does not because it is a matter of program safety. If you repeat `const` three times, you will summon the ghost of Dykstra to inspect your code and punish you if it doesn't meet his standards. No coder has ever survived the experience.

Comment: @T.E.D. You misspelled Dijkstra's name, he's going to be rolling in his grave ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow - Nah, I understand he's very easygoiAIEEEEEE!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C99 §6.7.3/4:

> If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same *specifier-qualifier-list*, either directly or via one or more **typedef** s, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

Yes, that is valid C99, and your discovery is correct.

Comment: Interesting! Why such difference in rules in C and C++? Any historical reasons?

Comment: Now to steal your text and @ybungalobill's text to get an accepted answer? mwahaha I won't dare to.

Comment: @Prasoon, I suspect C people are just too hung up on their macros, while C++ people do use proper `typedef`, not in need of such weird constructs. Note that `const const` is a C99 feature, which they describe as allowing "idempotent type qualifiers". Not valid in old C89.

Comment: @Johannes : Ah! Idempotent! Seem to have missed that. BTW why ain't I getting upvotes on the question? :)

Answer (score 17):

From the last C++0x draft, [dcl.type]:

> As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or in a type-specifier-seq or trailing-type-specifier-seq. The only exceptions to this rule are the following:
>
> — const can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
>
> — volatile can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
>
> — signed or unsigned can be combined with char, long, short, or int.
>
> — short or long can be combined with int.
>
> — long can be combined with double.
>
> — long can be combined with long.

Comment: @ybungalobill: if it were only for this... this is supposed to be the *trivial* part of C++. Think about writing the logic to get eg. the type of `a ? b : c` or the overload resolution rules in the presence of rvalue references, handling conversion sequences correctly, etc. This language is too complex !

Comment: Has anyone ever succeeded in writing a 100% standards-compliant, mostly bug-free C++ compiler?

Comment: @FredOverflow : Comeau is the best as far as standard compliance is under concern. :)

Answer (score 5):

C++ 2003 prohibits it in 7.1.5/1 "... redundant cv-qualifiers are prohibited except when introduced through the use of typedefs or template type arguments ...".

Answer (score 4):

The C++0x grammar appears to allow it:

> *cv-qualifier-seq*:
>
> - *cv-qualifier*  *cv-qualifier-seq* opt
>
> *cv-qualifier*:
>
> ```
>   const
>
>   volatile
> ```

---

Also, `[decl.type.cv]` appears to allow it:

> There are two *cv-qualifiers*, `const` and `volatile`.  If a *cv-qualifier* appears in a *decl-specifier-seq*, the *init-declarator-list* of the declaration shall not be empty. [ Note: 3.9.3 and 8.3.5 describe how cv-qualiﬁers aﬀect
>   object and function types.  — end note ] Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored. [ Note: For example, these
>   could be introduced by typedefs. — end note ]

Comment: Note that it just allows redundant cv-qualification (i.e `const T`, where `T` is a const qualified type). Which is a semantic sort of concern. It will not allow duplicate *cv-qualifiers*, which is ruled out by a different paragraph.