# What does "int * const const * b" mean?

Tags: c, declaration

`int * const const * b`

What does it mean? cdecl says `declare b as pointer to const const pointer to int`. 
Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const const` is redundant, it will reduce to `const`.

So let's rewrite that:

```
int * const *b;
```

So `b` is a pointer to a const pointer to an int. With an example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 5;
    int *ip = &i;
    int * const const * b = &ip;

    (**b)++; /* legal */
    (*b)++; /* illegal */
    (b)++; /* legal */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781222/duplicate-const-qualifier-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c), this is valid C99, but not valid C++ nor valid C89.

It's just a pointer to a const pointer to an integer. Const applies to what is on its left unless there is nothing on its left: then it applies on the right.

Here you just have redundant [redundancy](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Redundancy), which is repeated such that you're really sure that it is const and will not mutate.

Here you just have redundant [redundancy](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Redundancy), which is repeated such that you're really sure that it is const and will not mutate.

Even [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) tells that `b is pointer to const const pointer to int`.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to confusing declarations: **read it backwards.** Though in this case, you should first remove the redundant `const`.

So this:

```
int * const * b;
```

Becomes:

```
b      // b is a 
*      // pointer to
const  // a constant
*      // pointer to
int    // an int
```

In English, therefore: a pointer to a constant pointer to int.

As others have mentioned, this is a version of `int **`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as :

```
int * const * b;
```

which is a pointer to a `const` pointer to `int`.

`const const` is legal in C99/C11 and is the same as `const`:

> (C99, 6.7.3p4) "If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same specifier-qualifier-list, either directly or via one or more typedefs, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once."

But this is a constraint violation in C89:

> (C90, 6.5.3) "The same type qualifier shall not appear more than once in the same specifier list or qualifier list, either directly or via one or more typedefs."

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an `int **` 
  or a pointer to a pointer to an int
  or a pointer to an int array (where `int *` is a way of referencing an `int[]`

The `const` located after the `int *` means the pointer cannot be modified (though it's contents can) which is the opposite of `const int *`.

The second `const` is superflouous nad ignored.