# Duplicate CV qualifiers

Tags: c++, constants, volatile

I have a simple piece of code:

```
const const int a = 10;
```

It fails to compile with **gcc**:

```
error: duplicate 'const'
```

However **clang** compiles it with a warning:

```
warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
```

Microsoft compiler also generates a warning.

Also situation with `volatile` qualifier is the same.

From the [dcl.type] (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> As a general rule, at most one defining-type-specifier is allowed in the complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or in a defining-type-specifier-seq, and at most one type-specifier is allowed in a type-specifier-seq.
>   The only exceptions to this rule are the following:
>
> (2.1)
>       const can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
>
> (2.2)
>       volatile can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
>
> (2.3)
>       signed or unsigned can be combined with char, long, short, or int.
>
> (2.4)
>       short or long can be combined with int.
>
> (2.5)
>       long can be combined with double.
>
> (2.6)
>       long can be combined with long.

So I don't quite understand what does "as a general rule" means. Is this formally valid or not?

Also I found the related issue [Duplicate const qualifier allowed in C but not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781222/duplicate-const-qualifier-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c), but there discussion is mainly about c and c++ differences.

Comment: Which version of the standard are you quoting from? Which draft?

Comment: Get it from http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type. Actually I don't know to what version of the c++ standard it refers to.

Comment: eel.is holds the current tip of the C++ standard working draft. It's not a draft for a published version, but for a future version (C++20).

Comment: It's probably the latest C++20 draft, *but* the source directly used to generate the web-pages have commits not part of the C++ standard repository so I'd be a little bit wary of it.

Comment: Found http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf for c++17. The same is written there. Updated link in the question.

Comment: You can find linkable drafts of recent standard revision on https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp - It also holds an accurate WP draft.

Comment: I think this passage is open for interpretation (and maybe it shouldn't be). My personal interpretation is this: "as a general rule" = "this is the rule that applies everywhere where it *can* apply, unless stated otherwise".

Comment: Why would one write `const const`?

Comment: Well maybe, generally you are right. But in theory such situation may occur if somebody uses to much preprocessor macros. Also I am just curious about compiler differences.