# Does multiple `const` mean something?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, declaration

I realised that you can declare a variable like this:

```
const const const const int i;
```

I know the basics (but admittedly, I do a lot of mistakes with const poinsters) which is that `int *p` means that `p` is simply a `pointer to int`, or in C `(int*)`. I also know that `const int *p` means a `constant pointer to int`. The mistake many make is to believe that it prevents you from doing stuff like `*p=5`, but what it really does is to prevent you from doing `p=&x`, which is making it point to another object. After that I did some experiments with the help of https://cdecl.org/ and here is what I found

```
const int p                       : const int
int const p                       : const int (same as above)
const int *p                      : pointer to const int
int const *p                      : pointer to const int
int *const p                      : const pointer to int
const *int p                      : syntax error
const int *const p                : const pointer to const int
```

Nothing weird yet, but wait for it:

```
const int const *p                : pointer to const const int 
int const *const *p               : const pointer to const int
int const *const const const p    : const const const pointer to const int
const const int const const p     : const const const const int
```

Surely, it must a bug with https://cdecl.org/ ? Let's try to compile something.

```
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int const const *const *i)
{
    printf("%d\n", *i);
//    *i=5;
}

int main(void)
{
    const const const const int i;
    int const const const const *p = &i;
    int const const const *const *x = &i;
    int const const *const const *y =p;
    foo(&i);
    foo(p);
    foo(x);
    foo(y);
}

$ gcc foo.c 
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:13:39: warning: initialization of ‘const int * const*’ from incompatible pointer type ‘const int *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   13 |     int const const const *const *x = &i;
      |                                       ^
foo.c:14:38: warning: initialization of ‘const int * const*’ from incompatible pointer type ‘const int *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   14 |     int const const *const const *y =p;
      |                                      ^
foo.c:15:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   15 |     foo(&i);
      |         ^~
      |         |
      |         const int *
foo.c:3:34: note: expected ‘const int * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const int *’
    3 | void foo(int const const *const *i)
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
foo.c:16:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   16 |     foo(p);
      |         ^
      |         |
      |         const int *
foo.c:3:34: note: expected ‘const int * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const int *’
    3 | void foo(int const const *const *i)
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

So, my specific obeying-the-on-topic-criteria question is, does it mean anything to have several `const` in a variable? Is there any difference between a `const const int` and `const int`? Does it matter if it is a pointer or not? My less-specific question is wtf is going on here?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781222/duplicate-const-qualifier-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c answer your question? I guess you could consider it a bug with cdecl, but nobody should be writing code like that anyway…

Comment: @Ry- No it does not. It only says that it is valid. And it does not seem to be a bug either.

Comment: Well, okay, I’ll be specific: it means nothing.

Comment: And it doesn’t “only say that it is valid”, the meaning is right there in the quote: “… the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once”.

Comment: @Ry- I cannot find that quote

Comment: It’s between “C99 §6.7.3/4” and “Yes, that is valid C99, and your discovery is correct.” (If you have a browser with a “Find” function, the previously quoted bit should also be findable.) Also, “The mistake many make is to believe that it prevents you from doing stuff like `*p=5`, but what it really does is to prevent you from doing `p=&x`, which is making it point to another object” is incorrect – `const int *p` means exactly that `*p = 5` isn’t valid and `p = &x` can be. You’re thinking of `int* const p`.